# Docker bench - How to persist logs or supply log file argument

Tags: docker

I am following the tutorial to run docker bench from [its GitHub page](https://github.com/docker/docker-bench-security/blob/master/README.md)

I am executing it as follows:

```
C:/ docker ps 
<lists running containers>
C:/ docker run -it --net host --pid host --userns host --cap-add audit_control -e DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=$DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST -v /etc:/etc -v /usr/bin/docker-containerd:/usr/bin/docker-containerd -v /usr/bin/docker-runc:/usr/bin/docker-runc -v /usr/lib/systemd:/usr/lib/systemd -v /var/lib:/var/lib -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --label docker_bench_security docker/docker-bench-security
```

The docker bench command works fine, and I see the colored output with my PASS/WARNs and my total score out of the total checks at the bottom.

**The problem** is that docker bench says "By default the Docker Bench for Security script will run all available CIS tests and produce logs in the current directory named docker-bench-security.sh.log.json and docker-bench-security.sh.log"

However in my root (C:) where I executed the commands, I do not see these two files.

I have also tried running the same docker bench command above but with the optional log argument

`docker run docker/docker-bench-security..... -l logs.txt`

But I do not see any file get created (and if I premake the file it is not populated).

Any ideas on how I can capture my docker bench output in a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is likely created inside the container.

As you noticed you can set its path using the `-l path` option,
but if you want the file to appear on the host you need to mount
that path as a volume.

In other words you need to run the following command:

`docker run (...) -v /path/to/my-logs:/tmp/my-logs docker-bench-security (...) -l /tmp/my-logs/log.txt`

--where `(...)` are the existing parameters that you use.